# unable to Drop a table in My Sql, You have an error in your SQL syntax 1064

Tags: mysql

i have just make a table as Customer 1,
& now want to Drop that, so used DROP TABLE Customer 1. but my sql shows, 
You have an error in your SQL syntax 1064. i tried multiple combinations of above command, but still unable to do so.

Error - #1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '1' at line 1

Answer (score 1):

The issue here is likely to be the space in the table name. Have you tried the following?

```
DROP TABLE `Customer 1`;
```